# Duplicating a QGIS user profile

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I was wondering initially how one can rename a user profile in [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org) (3.4). It seems there is no feature for that in the GUI.

Eventually I wondered if it's possible to duplicate a user profile. I did not see any topic about this anywhere on the web but I concluded it might simply take to copy-paste the folder that contains the user profile data.

Answer (score 6):

What I did :

- I went to the folder with the user profiles. On my Debian OS, it was in `/home/<my user name>/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles`.
- I copied-paste the folder of the original user profile (in my case it was the default user). I renamed the folder.
- I restarted QGIS and it works fine.

I hope it helps somebody else who would be wondering.

Comment: I think that's a good way to do it for now. I've been working profile management for Thunderbird, etc. and that's about the same way they do it, even with a GUI